# Display Array ColumnWise

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to display an array of numbers. The output needs to be this:

```
10 25 29 13 46 30 26 57 41 34 88 52 60 77 82
```

I currently have it working but its not displaying column-wise, here is my output:

```
10 13 26 34 60 25 46 57 88 77 29 30 41 52 82
```

I found a similar question with answer on here but it was for rows that aren't all the same length, so I don't think it will be helpful to use it.

Here is my code (also I'm new to java):

```
public class test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

int rows = 3;
int cols = 5;


int intar [][] = {  {10, 13, 26, 34, 60} ,
                {25, 46, 57, 88, 77},
                {29, 30, 41, 52, 82} };



for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    System.out.print ( intar[i][j] + " " );
  }
}


}
}
```

Comment: You should get into the habit of using better names for loop indexes. In the real world, i and j will lead to confusion. If you had used rowIndex and colIndex, you might have found it easier to figure out where you went wrong.

Comment: This is just what my professor asked us to use (i, j)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a small change as follows:

From

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            System.out.print(intar[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
```

To

```
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.out.print(intar[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
```

Output in Console;

```
 10 25 29 13 46 30 26 57 41 34 88 52 60 77 82
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch the following two lines:

```
for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your for loop with this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    System.out.print ( intar[j][i] + " " );
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this might throw an exception (out of bounds).

Answer (score 0):

You're close, it's

```
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    System.out.print(intar[j][i] + " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: This will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @Jason - I ran it... 10 25 29 13 46 30 26 57 41 34 88 52 60 77 82

Comment: Sorry, didn't spot that you also changed the meaning of i and j. Simpler to just switch the position of the two for loops.

Answer (score -1):

Add a new line

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    System.out.print ( intar[i][j] + " " );
  }
    System.out.print ( "\n" );
}
```

BTW You will also want to do padding

Comment: This doesn't change the order of the numbers.